# Is it possible to dynamically set model for Eloquent Relationships?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I have 2 user roles. In database I have own profile tables for both of roles ( `model_profiles` and `client_profiles`). Is there any way to set related Profile model dynamically? I've tried this:

```
//User model:    
public function profile(){   
  return $this->role == 'model' ? $this->hasOne('App\Models\Model\Profile') : $this->hasOne('App\Models\Client\Profile');
}
```

But in this case I can't use some Eloquent methods like `User::with('profile')->whereIn('id', [1,2,3])->get();` because `$this->role` is `null` until user model is loaded.

Is there any way to use Profile model based on user role and don't lose any Eloquent query methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Polymorphic relationships ([More Information](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships))